# The proper way to invoke function template in main() having reference parameters in C++

Tags: templates, function

I have a template as below

```
    template<typename T>
T insert(T a[], int& n  ,const T& x)
{
    int i;
    for (i = n-1; i > 1 && x < a[i]; --i)
        a[i+1] = a[i];
    a[i+1] = x;
    ++n;
}
```

What's the correct way to invoke it in main()

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that is even correctly defined. Aren't you missing :: ?
Secondly, I don't see the template definition or its name.
Thirdly you're attributing a T return type to this function, but you're not even returning anything.

a correct template should look like this

```
template <typename T> class tMyExample
{
     public:
          tMyExample <T> () { // constructor code }
          insert (T a[], int &n, const T &x) { // your code here }
};

int main (void)
{
   tMyExample <int> MyExample;

   return 0;
}
```

Wll, my template definition is just the bare minimum. If you don't specialize it or add implementations outside the definition you get to another story. But the declaration inside a function (like main) is the same: template_name  identifier;

Honestly I never used [] in parameters, I use pointers (no need for allocations if you you arrays).